# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc - Error in the linkage of assembly

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly

I am trying to compile in Linux Mint 17.2 a `main.c` code and assembly code `pstring.s`.

When I try to link the codes, the `gcc` returns:
`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc`.

Does anyone know what I need to change in order to make it work?

```
gcc -m32 -g -c -o pstring.o pstring.s 

shay@shay-Latitude-E6410~/workspace1/targ3Mivne $ gcc -m32 -g -c -o main.o main.c

shay@shay-Latitude-E6410 ~/workspace1/targ3Mivne $ gcc -m32 -g -o a.out main.o pstring.o

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so when searching for
-lgcc_s /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s 

collect2: error: ld returned 1 
exit status
```

Comment: What version of gcc are you using? You using the multilib version? Can you show us the commands you use to compile and link?

Comment: [gcc -m32 -g -c -o pstring.o pstring.s
shay@shay-Latitude-E6410 ~/workspace1/targ3Mivne $ gcc -m32 -g -c -o main.o main.c
shay@shay-Latitude-E6410 ~/workspace1/targ3Mivne $ gcc -m32 -g -o a.out main.o pstring.o
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status]

Comment: Try installing these packages with the command `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib`

Comment: @MichaelPetch why does this work vs. a gcc compiled without multilib?

Comment: @sholsapp Without multilib the 32-bit version of libgcc isn't available. The 64-bit one can't be linked to 32-bit code which is the reason for the error in this question.

Answer (score 11):

Try installing these packages with the command `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib`

Without multilib the 32-bit version of libgcc isn't available. The 64-bit one can't be linked to 32-bit code which is the reason for the error in this question. – Michael Petch